# How to automatically add a protected key to ssh-agent on startup?

Tags: linux, ssh-agent, gdm, gnome-keyring, awesome-wm

I am using gdm to start awesome wm via .xinitrc.
I like awesomes usability and gnomes integrity and so far most of the startup programs work fine but i am fighting with ssh-agent. When starting gnome my password protected id_rsa is automatically added to ssh-agent on startup.. i am trying to achive the same with my .xinitrc started awesome wm.

My .xinitrc:

```
/usr/libexec/at-spi-registryd &
/usr/libexec/gdu-notification-daemon &
gnome-screensaver &
/usr/libexec/vino-server --sm-disable &
/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=keyring &
/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=secrets &
/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=ssh &
/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=pkcs11 &
/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=gpg &
/usr/libexec/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1 &
/usr/libexec/evolution/2.32/evolution-alarm-notify &
/usr/libexec/gnome-settings-daemon &
gnome-power-manager &
gsettings-data-convert &
gnome-volume-control-applet &
nm-applet --sm-disable &
exec /usr/bin/ck-launch-session /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/ssh-agent -- awesome
```

How does Gnome tackle this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GNOME stores your SSH key passphrases in GNOME Keyring, which (the *`login`* keyring) is **unlocked with your login password by `pam_gnome_keyring`**:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth           ...
auth           ...
auth           optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so

session        ...
session        ...
session        optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
```

However, your current setup will not work with this, as you are starting a `ssh-agent` at the last step, **overwriting any environment variables that *gnome-keyring* may have set.** Remove `ssh-agent`, and try adding this after all keyring daemon processes:

```
eval $(gnome-keyring-daemon --start)
```

Keep in mind also that `gnome-keyring-daemon` publishes a few environment variables over DBus which are then read by `gnome-shell`, **which Awesome doesn't do.** That, *and* you are **starting the DBus session bus *after* all daemons have started,** so they may be unable to connect to your session at all.

One more thing: Many of the daemons **must be started *inside* a ConsoleKit session** – the PolicyKit authentication agent, for example. You'll have more luck if you replace your entire `~/.xinitrc` script with:

```
exec ck-launch-session dbus-launch --exit-with-session ~/.xinitrc-session
```

then use `~/.xinitrc-session` to launch the rest of GNOME.

---

You can go an easier way. Use the standard `ck-launch-session dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session`, and just **tell GNOME session manager to launch Awesome as the window manager. [Follow the official instructions.](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Quickly_Setting_up_Awesome_with_Gnome)**

Abridged form for GNOME 2:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications/
cp /usr/share/applications/awesome.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
cat >> ~/.local/share/applications/awesome.desktop
X-GNOME-WMName=Awesome
X-GNOME-WMSettingsModule=awesome
X-GNOME-Autostart-Phase=WindowManager;Panel
X-GNOME-Provides=windowmanager;panel
X-GNOME-Autostart-Notify=true
[Ctrl-D]
gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/session/required_components/windowmanager --type string awesome
```

Comment: Very nice answer. Does all this work the same way in Gnome 2 & 3?

Comment: @honk: GNOME 3 uses the same Keyring (first part), but handles the session stuff (second part) somewhat differently. The Awesome wiki page has instructions for both.

Comment: as it turned out ssh-agent is started by gdm before .xinitrc is run. `eval $(gnome-keyring-daemon --start)` before execing awesome did the trick so there realy where just the environment variables missing. thanks for pushing me in the right direction.

Comment: @mugen: I hope you did read the entire post, not just the first ⅓.

Comment: Of course i did. Using awesome as Gnome windowmanager did usually work with the instructions from the awesome wiki but did not recently. .xinitrc is executed via `/usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/ssh-agent -- /etc/X11/gdm/Xsession custom`. So a DBus session and ssh-agent are allready running. For consolekit dependent programs like nm-applet to work i did not have to do anything else than launch awesome itself inside a console kit session. The environment variables realy were the missing part.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any particular reason not to use [pam_ssh](http://pam-ssh.sourceforge.net/)? I'm finding it rather convenient.

Comment: I have everything running with software that is pulled in as dependencies anyway. In the end there was a single line missing. So there was no reason to use another piece of software. But thanks for mentioning it, I will definitely take a closer look at it.

Comment: Last time I used pam_ssh, it crashed and burned upon trying to import an ECDSA key, leaving me unable to login. (Admittely, gnome-keyring does not support it either, but at least it fails gracefully.)